# Can't get CUBEVALUE to filter by date value in cell

Tags: excel, data-modeling, powerpivot

My data model has a column named **rowDate**. This column has several repeating instances of dates due to the fact that there are multiple rows of data for different times of a single day.

I've written a measure that sums the values in another column from the data model that I want to pull from. (We'll call this **MyMeasure**.)

I'm trying to write a CUBEVALUE formula that extracts the total of **MyMeasure** when **rowDate** equals the value of a cell in a worksheet. (This will allow the result of the CUBEVALUE to change based on the date that the user inputs into cell B2.)

e.g.

Cell B2 = "2018-06-29" (date formatted)

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[MyMeasure]","[Summary Data].[rowDate].["&$B$2&"]")
```

This always returns #N/A. I have another column with data (a number) that I can write the exact same CUBEVALUE formula, but referencing the appropriate cell, and it works just fine. It's just this date column that I can't figure out.

Comment: What does the syntax look like if you add a PivotTable with the values field you're interested in, and generate a GETPIVOTDATA function by typing = and then clicking on the cell containing the equivalent data you're after? Perhaps this will help you track down any issues with your date syntax. For instance, I just whipped up a simple dataset and see that GETPIVOTDATA returns `=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of Value]",$D$2,"[Table1].[Date]","[Table1].[Date].&[2018-07-04T00:00:00]")`

Comment: I get the same thing. I modified my CUBEVALUE formula to match, added a helper column to concentrate my cell value to return exactly that date format, and now it returns blank instead of #N/A, so I guess that's... something!

Comment: Try `=CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Summary Data].[rowDate].["&$B$2&"]")` and if you get an error then it might be due to the date format in B2.

Comment: It did throw an error initially, but I eventually got it to work by using `=CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Summary Data].[rowDate].["&TEXT($B$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"]")`. Unfortunately adding the same modifier to the cell reference does not work with the CUBEVALUE formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution in [this thread](https://forum.powerpivotpro.com/forums/topic/date-format-used-with-pp/). The trick is to format the date in your targeted cell inline using the TEXT function to match the cube's default date format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS).

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[MyMeasure]","[Summary Data].[rowDate].&["&TEXT($B$2,"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS")&"]")
```